# LM2596S-ADJ DC to DC buck converter

Tags: dc, buck, converter

[image]

Does the Schottky diode current rating affect the performance of a DC to DV buck converter when loaded? I'm using a 1N5822 Schottky diode instead of a 1N5825 on a National Semiconductor LM2596S-ADJ based buck converter design.

My output voltage drops when I load the circuit with a 100 Ω or 50 Ω resistor. The voltage drops by nearly 0.25 V and 0.40 V respectively.

My design is not yet on a PCB, I'm testing it on a breadboard.

[image]

Comment: Actually, such level of drop indicates that either Cout is too low or DC resistance of L1 is too high.

Comment: how can resistance for L1 be measured?

Comment: Datasheet shows actually. Or simply, measure the voltage across it while the circuit is loaded then divide that voltage by the load current.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the diode voltage drop \$V_f\$ in a buck appears in the input-to-output transfer function \$\frac{V_{out}}{V_{in}}\$ weighted by \$(1-D)\$, \$D\$ being the duty ratio. So if the \$V_f\$ is too big, you will see a drop in the output but the loop should compensate by an increase of the duty ratio. Nevertheless, efficiency will drop as \$V_f\$ grows especially in CCM when \$V_{out}\$ is much smaller than \$V_{in}\$. As the diode voltage drop at a given current is directly related to its die size, a higher current rating type will imply a lower \$V_f\$.

Comment: ok thank you. I was testing the circuit with that same 1N5822 didoe and all of a sudden the voltage at the output is higher than that on the input(higher than voltage supplied). Could the Lm2596 be dead.

Comment: It's strange: if the IC is dead, the series-pass switch is likely to be shorted. In that case, Vout and Vin are almost equal. If Vout is larger than Vin, either the measurement is wrong or you have unintentionally built a boost which I doubt with that circuit.

Comment: how do i check if ic is dead. any actual menthod you know

Answer (score 0):

> My output voltage drops when i load the circuit by a 100 ohm resistor
>   or 50 ohm resistor. Drops by nearly 0.25V and 0.40V respectively.

Then either your input supply voltage can't supply the current needed to operate the chip correctly under load or your breadboarding and ground techniques are poor. These, and naivety in taking accurate measurements can easily account for the discrepencies you see.